# RequireAll in Apache 2.4.41 (Ubuntu) not working

Tags: apache-2.4

The directive below, to limit access to a site to a single IP address, has been working happily for months but I suspect a recent update to Apache may have changed the behavior.

Instead of limiting the access to a single IP address it completely blocks all access to the site.

Has anyone had a similar experience and knows of a work around ?

```
<Location "/testqc">
   <RequireAll>
      Require ip 192.168.0
   </RequireAll>  
    ProxyPass ajp://192.168.0.XXX:XXXX/testqc
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://192.168.0.XXX:XXXX/testqc
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually a router change that altered the apparent ip source address.  All good now.